# UIView: How to check if touches ended inside the same view in which they began

Tags: uiview, three20, uitouch, touchesbegan

In `AcaniUsers`, I've created a grid of `ThumbView : UIView` instances inside of a `UITableView`. All `thumbViews` have a width of `kThumbSize`. How do I detect if touches ended inside the same view in which they began?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works, but I'm not sure if it's the best way to go about it. I think so though.

Since all `thumbViews` have a width of `kThumbSize`, just check in `touchesEnded` that the x-coordinate of the `locationInView` of the `UITouch` instance (assuming `self.multipleTouchEnabled = NO`) is less than or equal to `kThumbSize`. This means the touches ended inside the `thumbView`. No need to check the y-coordinate because if the touches move vertically, the `tableView`, which contains the `thumbViews`, scrolls and the touches are cancelled.

Do the following in `ThumbView : UIView` (whose instances are subviews of a `UITableView`):

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"touchesEnded %@", touches);
    CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] /* only one */ locationInView:self];
    if (touchPoint.x >= 0.0f && touchPoint.x <= kThumbSize) {
        [(ThumbsTableViewCell *)self.superview.superview thumbTouched:self];
    }
}
```

To only register touches on one `thumbView` at a time, you also probably want to set `self.exclusiveTouch = YES;` in the `init` instance method of `ThumbView`.

Comment: You can write nicer code by doing this: `if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.bounds, touchPoint)) { ... }`. :)

Answer (score 9):

In the view extension you use;

Swift 4:

```
open override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
    guard let touchPoint = touches.first?.location(in: self) else { return }
    guard self.bounds.contains(touchPoint) else { return }
    // Do items for successful touch inside the view
}
```